# is there a way to shorten / optimise this code to make multiple wavy lines of different colours?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

using p5.js i need to create multiple wavy colourd lines, i have written out the folowing code but i would like to optimize and shorten the code. would there be any other additional ways to make this? i would like to know if there are any easier ways to achieve this output using curveVertext for example and using loops.

```js
function setup() {
    let = new Curve(); // a new curve system
    initalize(); // initalize
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); // the canvas width and height 
    sketch(); // draw it
}

function Curve() {
    thick = 5; // initial stroke weight
    detail = 0.02; // this is the curve detail
    num = 150; // the number of lines to draw
    curves = []; // this will hold all curves

    initalize = function() { // initalize the lines and  random colour
        let pos = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            curves.push(new Curves(pos, detail, color(random(255), random(255), random(255))));
            pos = pos + thick;
        }
    }

    sketch = function() {
        noFill();
        strokeWeight(thick); // define the weight of strokes
        for (let i = 0; i < curves.length; i++) { // loop the lines
            curves[i].display();
        }
    }
}

function Curves(begin, waves, col) { // lines
    off = 0.0; // offset of curves
    wave = waves; // the noise detail of lins
    dec = col; // the line colors
    shape = 100; // adjustable range a line can curve 
    start = begin - shape; // the y starting point offset by the range


    this.display = function() {
        stroke(col); // set the color of lines
        beginShape();
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x += 3) { // loops the width of canvas
            off = off + wave; // calculate new y offset
            let y = (noise(off) * shape); // calculate y distance
            curveVertex(x, begin + y); // begins the curve
        }
        endShape();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even if you use a [Shape](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-Shape), the code doesn't get any shorter. Some where you need to create the "waves" in a loop. It would take some math to join [bezier()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/bezier) or [curve()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curve) into a long smooth wave. [curveVertex()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curveVertex) seems to be the best solution.

Comment: I just want to say that you just made my head explode with `let = new Curve();` followed by using functions on that `Curve` instance in the global scope. I had no idea that was possible, also it makes me feel a little queasy to be honest .

Comment: Oh, ‍♂️ I see why those calls `initalize` and `sketch` are working! It's because your class definition is broken. You should be declaring `this.initialize = function ...` and `this.sketch = function ...`. I have no idea why JavaScript doesn't just throw a bad syntax error on `let = new Curve()` because that is just nonsense. Hopefully you've adopted proper modern class declaration sytnax as Rabbid76 suggests below.

Answer (score 1):

Some where you need to create the "waves" in a loop. It would take some math to join [bezier()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/bezier) or [curve()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curve) into a long smooth wave. [curveVertex()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curveVertex) seems to be the best solution.

However, you can clean up the code using classes:

```js
let curves;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); // the canvas width and height 
    curves = new Curves(150, 5, 0.02, 100); // a new curve system
    noLoop();
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    curves.sketch();
}

class Curves {
    constructor(num, thick, detail, shape) {
        this.thick = thick; // initial stroke weight
        this.curves = []; // this will hold all curves
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            this.curves.push(new Curve(this.thick * i, detail, shape, color(random(255), random(255), random(255))));
        }
    }

    sketch() {
        noFill();
        strokeWeight(this.thick); // define the weight of strokes
        for (let i = 0; i < this.curves.length; i++) { // loop the lines
            this.curves[i].display();
        }
    }
}

off = 0.0; // offset of curves
class Curve { 
    constructor(begin, wave, shape, col) { // lines    
        this.col = col; // the line colors
        this.vertices = []
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x += 3) { // loops the width of canvas
            off = off + wave; // calculate new y offset
            let y = (noise(off) * shape); // calculate y distance
            this.vertices.push([x, begin + y]);
        }
    }

    display() {
        stroke(this.col); // set the color of lines
        beginShape();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.vertices.length; i++) {
            curveVertex(...this.vertices[i])
        }
        endShape();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your help, i appreciate it :)